# Find Replace not working in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Find/Replace in Notepad++ does not return a results. I have tried Normal, Extended, Regular Expression and searching in all open documents, saving the document and opening existing.

[image]

Comment: In the picture, the cursor may be on line 3 and the direction is set to UP. To find 'Test' on line 1, check the 'Down' direction in Find dialog box.

Comment: Wrap around is enable, even so selecting the line of search text, below or above makes no difference.

Comment: Are you sure there're no non-printable characters somewhere?

Comment: I was having trouble with a file at first then I created a new file and typed the example out manually. Even so it's not matching "Whole word Only" so it should return the part it can match. It does the same with a regex, if I search "/s" in a file with hundreds of spaces it returns no matches.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by performing an uninstall and reinstall of Notepad ++.

Comment: Why to install? Just download the .7z or .zip file from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/, extract it, then run as portable from any partition/drive.